# Filter for a class and role in Playwright?

Tags: typescript, playwright

I want to filter for a link with the `navbar__brand` class on the Playwright website - via Playwright:

[image]

My code:

```
test("homepage has title and links to intro page", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/");

  const links = page.getByRole("link").locator(".navbar__brand");

  const count = await links.count();
  console.log("count is " + count); // zero instead of the expected one!
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't it find the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not finding the link because the locator is only searching children of the `<a>` element, already found by `getByRole`. In other words, it can't find itself in its children.

If I understand your HTML correctly, the `:scope` pseudoselector should work, which essentially lets an element query itself as well as its children:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.28.1

const html = `<a class="navbar__brand" href="/">hello world</a>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const result = await page.getByRole("link")
    .locator(":scope.navbar__brand") // or ".navbar__brand:scope"
    .textContent();
  console.log(result); // => hello world
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Comment: that worked perfectly fine and I learned from your sample how to create an example that even includes the HTML to test against - great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't complicate a simple problem, just use CSS locator as below:

```
const links= await page.locator('a[class="navbar__brand"]').all()
```