# Is there a way to create a custom css selector in Playwright to check for both a data-testId and a css style at the same time?

Tags: typescript, playwright

I have a UI element with both a `data-testid` and a css attribute of `style='display: table-row;`. Right now, I use `getByTestId` to grab that test id and then chain a locator to it to check for the `style` attribute. However, that looks for an element with that `style` nested within an element that has the `data-testid`.

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a custom css selector to match for both here.

My current LoC is

```
this.formFieldError = page.getByTestId("sign-up-error").locator("[style='display: table-row']")
```

The HTML for the element in question is:

```html
<tr data-testid="sign-up-error" class="formvalidate_error password_error" style="display: table-row;">
<td></td>
<td class="error_msg">Password must be at least 10 characters long</td>
</tr>
```

and I'm trying to get the row element. It shares the same data-testid as other rows, the difference is that when the element is displayed, the `style` attribute changes.

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74725145/6243352), try `.locator(":scope[style='display: table-row']")`. That said, selecting by a style property is generally not good practice. I would add a test id to that element too, or use something like `getByRole("row")`. If you show your HTML structure, it'd be easier to answer this more effectively.

Comment: @ggorlen makes sense - there IS a data-testID associated with the element. I'll update the question to include the HTML.

Comment: I would select this by text: `page.getByTestId("sign-up-error").getByText("Password must be at least 10 characters long")`. Or, if you're testing, select by the test id and assert the test. The HTML is helpful, but without the other elements and a bit more context, it's still hard to determine what makes it unique. By "I would add a test id to that element too" I mean the child table row, which doesn't have a test id after your update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a test id to the `<td>` with the error in it so you can select it directly. This is probably the easiest approach.

If it's not feasible to change the markup, I'd select by the text:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.42.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><table>
<tr data-testid="sign-up-error" class="formvalidate_error password_error" style="display: table-row;">
  <td></td>
  <td class="error_msg">Password must be at least 10 characters long</td>
</tr></table></body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page
    .getByTestId("sign-up-error")
    .getByRole("cell")
    .getByText("Password must be at least 10 characters long")
    .waitFor();
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Or by the child class, if you can't specify the text (even partially):

```js
await page
  .getByTestId("sign-up-error")
  .locator("td.error_msg")
  .waitFor();
```

Or using the `:scope` pseudoselector to include the cell `<td>` itself:

```js
await page
  .getByTestId("sign-up-error")
  .getByRole("cell")
  .locator(":scope.error_msg")
  .waitFor();
```

A selector like `"[style='display: table-row']"` is *really* brittle and strongly discouraged. Even adding a semicolon to the inline style attribute causes the selector to fail the ultra-strict exact match:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

const htmlWithoutSemi = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><table>
<tr style="display: table-row"><td>asdf</td></tr>
</table></body></html>`;

const htmlWithSemi = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><table>
<tr style="display: table-row;"><td>asdf</td></tr>
</table></body></html>`;

test("works when there's no semicolon", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(htmlWithoutSemi);
  await expect(page.locator("[style='display: table-row']")).toBeVisible();
});

test("fails when there's a semicolon", async ({page}) => {
  test.fail(); // we expect this to fail, unfortunately
  await page.setContent(htmlWithSemi);
  await expect(page.locator("[style='display: table-row']")).toBeVisible();
});
```

You can use [attribute selector variants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like `*=` and `~=` to avoid these failures, but these can open up other problems. Generally speaking, it's better to avoid CSS attributes regardless of whether you're testing or web scraping, particularly `style=` attributes, as these can be very free-text, tend to change often and can be (correctly) moved to stylesheets without notice.

Comment: This is great - I ended up adding a filter to the testid locator and filtered by role and name (adding in the actual error string). Works like a charm. Managed to avoid dealing with the CSS altogether which, agreed, is far too brittle.

Comment: Good to hear. Feel free to add your own answer with your solution.